# Can skewness (the third moment of a distribution) be interpreted as the variance of variance?

Tags: variance, descriptive-statistics, skewness

I have read somewhere that the skewness can be interpreted as the variance of variance. Can you provide me with an intuition on how it may be the case?

Comment: It's hard to imagine what your source might have been saying. Applying the definitions, it is apparent that the variance of a (sample) variance requires moments through the *fourth* order.  Skewness (which is a function only of moments through the third order) is insufficient.  Moreover, the problem with skewness becomes obvious when you consider that it's unitless, while the variance of a variance would be measured in the original units of the data raised to the fourth power.

Comment: In addition to whubers excellent points, consider that for the normal distribution the skewness is exactly zero, while the variance of the sample variance is certainly not zero

Comment: @whuber I answered without seeing your comment; my post echoes yours but is briefer. It'd be better for your answer to be there than mine and if you'd like to post an answer I'll happily remove mine (which would add nothing whatever)

Answer (score 3):

No, skewness isn't variance of (sample) variance. The variance of the sample variance is affected by moments to fourth order.

[Note also that skewness is not the third moment.]